# How can we acces one npm package file in other?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am having two projects A and B
I have made npm package of A.
A is having foll structure:

```
A: 

 - utils

    - a.js
 - package.json
```

I have imported this npm package in project B.
I want to call this a.js directly through script of package.json of project B.

How can we do that?